# Does RepeatWith parameter work in SSRS 2008?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

Does anyone know if the RepeatWith parameter of a Line works in SSRS 2008?

We have a report that has a header, rectangle, and footer.  Inside the rectangle is the data table, table1.  It is an invoice form that needs to repeat vertical lines not only at the edges of the rectangle, but also to separate the columns of the table, and the lines need to always go to the bottom of the page, so using the right and left borders of the text boxes in the tables won't work.

We got this to work in SSRS 2005 by drawing vertical lines inside the rectangle to separate the columns of data, and setting the RepeatWith Property of each line to be table1 (our data table that is inside the rectangle).

We are currently trying to convert to SSRS 2008 and the lines only display on the first page of the report, they will not repeat on multiple pages in preview or PDF.

Has anyone been able to get this to work in SSRS 2008?   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the Groups Preview pane, choose Advanced Mode. Select a static row and looking at the properties window. You will see properties called RepeatOnNewPage, and KeepWithGroup, these properties work together. If you choose RepeatOnNewPage, you will have to set the KeepWithGroup, all rows in the same group or outside the group (all static headers) need these properties set the same. There is also a setting in the Tablix Properties, on the General tab for Repeat header rows on each page.

Comment: This is not working with  "Line" in other case already tried its working fine.