# RDLC Report - Repeating vertical lines on all pages

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, rdlc

I am designing an Invoice (Bill) using RDLC, WinForms, C# in Visual Studio 2012. The Invoice could span from 1 to N pages. I am using Tablix to show the Invoice details (line items) in the Report Body. An Invoice may contain 1 to N line items.

As per the design requirement the Tablix Columns need to be separated by Visible Vertical Lines when the report is viewed, printed or exported. These lines need to start at the top near the Tablix Header and run to the end of the page i.e. they cover the Report Body from top to bottom. The Body part of the Invoice looks something like this:

```
 | SNo.| Code      | Quantity   | Particulars   | Rate   | Amount |
 |     |           |            |               |        |        |
 |     |           |            |               |        |        |
 |     |           |            |               |        |        |
 |     |           |            |               |        |        |  
 |     |           |            |               |        |        |
 |     |           |            |               |        |        |
```

I thought of 2 options to do this:

1. Turn ON the border of the Tablix on all 4 sides.
   This does not work because if the records are less, then the lines are only shown half way through the page.
2. Turn OFF the border of the Tablix on all 4 sides and use the LINE OBJECTs to decorate the Invoice and extend it till the end of the page. This works only on the first page and no Lines are shown on the subsequent pages.

There were other options that I thought of, but did not give me a clean result and was a compromise in other areas.

Please help me as I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In a VS2005 application (no Tablix) I had to:

1. set body height so that the sum of header height + body height + footer height + top/bottom margin = PageSize.Height
2. put one rectangle for every column OVER my table (i.e. 1 rectangle for SNo. column, 1 rectangle for Code column)
3. set RepeatWith of every rectangle to my table

I think the same solution will work for VS2012, Tablix and Line: try to set Line.RepeatWith to your Tablix.

Comment: tezzo, thanks for the answer. My Body height is set in the way you have mentioned. This is the value I have set in the Body height property. In Visual Studio 2012 there is a property called RepeatWith. I have added a rectangle and set the property RepeatWith to Tablix1. Unfortunately this still does not work.

Comment: So the rectangle is still printed only in the first page?

Comment: Yes the rectangle is printed only on the first page.

Comment: Bad news? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269371/does-repeatwith-parameter-work-in-ssrs-2008

Comment: Hmmm... I hope somebody comes up with some answer or a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list for displaying data with a table inside it.

Then have a list height full upto bottom. Draw vertical lines inside list upto bottom.

Then in list group, provide following expression.

`ROWNUMBER(nothing)\20`.

20 is the number of lines required on one page.